# Use of unassigned local variable error

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

I am receiving an error:

> "Use of unassigned local variable 'PostData'"

when compiling the following statements below within a method. My intent is take a "string" value containing an XML SOAP header and convert it to a `XMLDictionaryWriter` object. See my code below:

```
Stream PostData;
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x509.CreateX509SoapEnvelope());
PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // error here
XmlDictionaryWriter xmlwriter = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(PostData, Encoding.ASCII);
request.Headers.WriteHeaderContents(0,xmlwriter);
```

FYI, the output of `x509.CreateX509SoapEnvelope()` is a string and I tested that part and it works. I marked the code above to show where the error occurs.Need assistance with the error and how to fix it ?

Comment: Is that the entire code block? You declared `Stream PostData` but didn't construct it into anything, so it's just sitting around as `null`. When you do `.Write` against it you will get a null reference exception.

Comment: XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter accepts a stream type hence my need to convert my string value to a stream and then pass if as an argument when XMLDictionaryWriter is instantiated. Is there a better way of reworking my code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never assigned a value to `PostData`. Thus, its default value is `null` and the compiler is smart enough to tell you this is a bad thing to do (if it permitted your code as is, you will get a runtime `NullReferenceException`). You need to instantiate an instance of a class that is a `Stream` (`Stream` is abstract and so you need a concrete instance) and assign it to `PostData`.

Comment: My plan is to take the string output and pass it as an argument to the WriteHeaderContents method which either accepts a XMLDictionaryWrite or XMLWriter type .. is there a better way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `PostData`, but not initialised it.

You need to have:

```
Stream PostData = new StreamWriter(filename);
```

at the bare minimum. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) for more information on the various initialisers.

Comment: I do not have a filename to specify.. but I need to write the contents of "string" output to the Stream. How do I instantiate to accomodate this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was after the same thing you are.  I used a MemoryStream which didn't need a file in order to instantiate.  See reference below:

[MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)